# Is the rowspace of a matrix $A$ the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

In the answers to this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605579/how-do-we-know-that-nullspace-and-row-space-of-a-matrix-are-orthogonal-complemen/4605582#4605582), it was shown that the nullspace is the orthogonal complement of the rowspace of a matrix $A$.

Is it also true that the rowspace is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace? If so, what is the argument used to prove this?

Let $y$ be a vector in the rowspace. Then, for any $x$ in the nullspace, we know that $x$ is perpendicular to $y$ by definition of nullspace (vectors $x$ that solve $Ax=0$). Thus, the rowspace is contained in the orthogonal complement of the nullspace.

Now let $y$ be a vector in the orthogonal complement of the nullspace. $y$ is perpendicular to every vector in the nullspace, but is it necessarily in the rowspace?

Comment: Orthogonal complement is a symmetric relation, so yes.

Comment: If $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ then $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$. So, if $W = V^\perp$ then $W^\perp = (V^\perp)^\perp = V$.

Comment: Hint: The product Ax can be written in terms of the dot product of vectors as follows:$$A\mathbf{x}=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{a}_1\cdot \mathbf{x}\\
 \mathbf{a}_2\cdot \mathbf{x}\\
 \vdots\\
 \mathbf{a}_m\cdot \mathbf{x}\\
\end{array} \right] .$$

Answer (score 1):

In a paragraph of Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra* he provides the argument.

> If $v$ is orthogonal to the nullspace, it must be in the row space.
> Otherwise we could add this $v$ as an extra row of the matrix, without
> changing its nullspace. The row space would gro, which breaks the law
> $r+(n-r)=n$. We conclude that the nullspace complement is exactly the
> row space.